# Help ranking and finding solutions for a three equation matrix with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello, I have to rank the following system of equations (as a matrix):
1  2  a | 1
1  a  3 | 3
x  11 a | b

And determine when it has a single solutions, infinite solutions or no solutions.
I'm stuck ranking this matrix and need some help...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: One does not use "rank" as a verb because "ranking" would be comparing this matrix with other ones. One says "find the rank".

Answer (score 1):

Start with the augmented matrix of the system

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 \\1 && a && 3 && 3 \\ 1 && 11 && a && b \end{bmatrix} $

After eliminating the $(2,1)$ and $(3,1)$ entries, it becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 \\0 && a-2 && 1 && 2 \\ 0 && 9 && a - 2 && b - 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Interchange rows $(2)$ and $(3)$ then divide row $(2)$ by $(9)$

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 \\ 0 && 1 && \dfrac{a-2}{9} && \dfrac{b-1}{9} \\ 0 && a - 2 && 1 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $

Eliminate the $(3, 2)$ entry

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 2 && 1 \\
0 && 1 && \dfrac{a-2}{9} && \dfrac{b-1}{9} \\
0 && 0 && 1 - \dfrac{(a-2)^2}{9} && 2 - \dfrac{(a-2)(b-1)}{9} \end{bmatrix} $

From here, it follows that the system will have a unique solution only if $\dfrac{(a-2)^2}{9} \ne 1 $, which means $ a \ne 5 $ and $ a \ne -1 $.

Now, if $ a = 5 $ then to have infinite solutions we must have

$ 2 - \dfrac{b-1}{3} = 0 $ , i.e. $ b = 7 $

and there will be no solutions if $ b \ne 7 $

and if $a = -1  $ then to have infinite soluions we must have

$ 2 + \dfrac{b-1}{3} = 0 $, i.e. $ b = -5 $

and there will be no solutions if $ b \ne -5 $

To summarize:

1. Unique solution if $ a \ne 5 $ and $ a \ne -1$
2. Infinite solutions if $ a = 5 $ and $b = 7$ or $a = -1$ and $b= -5$
3. No solutions if $a = 5$ and $ b \ne 7 $ or $a = -1$ and $b \ne -5$